# Microsoft Cloud App Security (MCAS) and SharePoint Online integration - redirection not working properly

Tags: azure, sharepoint

I have successfully integrated SharePoint Online with Microsoft Cloud App Security (MCAS) via Azure Conditional Access policy (session control). Request to SharePoint site is routed through mcas proxy as per design. However, end the end of all the redirections, MCAS is sending me to default site in SharePoint site collections as opposed to redirecting me to the site I have requested.

Here is the flow -

1. Request to https://aspnet4you2.sharepoint.com/sites/TestTeamSite
2. I am being redirected to top level mcas domain
   (https://aspnet4you2.sharepoint.com.mcas.ms/) after all the
   redirections required for authentication. This is a problem since, I
   ask for something and I got a different thing!
3. Since I know the
   path, I changed the path in the url to
   https://aspnet4you2.sharepoint.com.mcas.ms/sites/TestTeamSite
4. This time my request is honored but it does not meet the user
   experience.

Anyone experiencing similar issue with this kind of redirection from MCAS?

I am sharing the request flow from browser developer tool for further clarification.

[image]

Comment: I still don’t have the true solution but I wanted to share a temporary workaround. Microsoft Cloud App Security (mcas) is always redirecting me to SharePoint Communication Site which happened to be the default root site for the tenant. Interestingly, the url ends with mcas.ms. So, I updated the communication site page with web links of the sites I need to visit. It renders the links with mcas url and I just click the link. It works but it's not expected user experience.

Answer (score 1):

I have been working with Microsoft mcas support on this issue for few days. There is no solution to the problem at this time but Microsoft is working on the fix.

The underlying issue with the use of Authentication Context at the Azure Conditional Access policy. If you use app (SharePoint Online) in AAD CA, redirection works fine. One of the Azure AD authentication step is dropping the context (url path and query) when Authentication Context is used at Conditional Access policy with Session Control. Mcas team is collaborating with Azure AD team to resolve the problem but no time line is given to me.

Keep in mind Authentication Context in Conditional Access is a Preview feature. Glad we are able to identify the issue before public release!

Update as of 08/23/2021: Microsoft MCAS product team fixed the issue and redirection is working fine. We are no longer losing the context. I was collaborating with AAD and MCAS team and we found context was missing at call to /_layouts/15/contextflow.aspx. RpsContextCookie cookie didn't set the context correctly. Don't know the root cause at this time but the issue was at the backend and MCAS product team resolved it.